# Iterative/Looped Substitute without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, substitution

### Abridged Question:

If I have a concatenated string of "|#|#|#|...|#|", how can I apply a multiplier to each of the numbers and update the concatenated text?  For example, for |4|12|8|, multiply by a factor of 2 and update the concatenated text to |8|24|16|.

#### Background

I have three columns of interest.  The first column contains a date, the second an amount or factor, and the third column concatenates data into the format "|#|#|...|#|" (e.g., |2|5|, |2|5|12|, |4|12|, etc.).  At times, a multiplying factor needs to be applied to the concatenated data, and the individual numbers would need to be updated accordingly.

An example would be—

```
Date        Amt     Concatenated Data
01/01/18    2       |2|
01/05/18    5       |2|5|
02/06/18    12      |2|5|12|
03/25/18    -3      |4|12|
03/31/18    8       |4|12|8|
04/01/18    F2      |8|24|16|  (factor of 2 applied)
04/15/18    12      |8|24|16|12|
04/01/18    F1/4    |2|6|4|3|  (factor of 1/4 applied)
```

With a formula, how can I apply the factor to the concatenated data, and update the individual numbers?

I'm bound by the following conditions:

- Excel 2007, so no TEXTJOIN function
- No VBA or UDFs (due to security policies)
- Individual numbers are dynamic (i.e., I can't use a static value for the "old_text" parameter of the SUBSTITUTE formula)
- Amount of individual numbers within concatenated data is also dynamic (may contain one number, or may contain dozens of different numbers)

I can pull out the individual numbers using an array formula.  I can even then multiply those numbers by the factor to produce an array result.  However, I can't rebuild the concatenated data, because CONCATENATE doesn't work on an array.  I've also tried SUBSTITUTE, but I can't iterate through the "|" separators.  I can only substitute a given segment (e.g., change all entries of "|2|" to "|4|").  Nesting SUBSTITUTE or using individual columns won't work, since it could potentially involve dozens of instances.

Just to add some info on the concatenated data:

- Amt>0, then value is concatenated to the end of the previous concatenated value
- Amt<0, begin reducing individual numbers in concatenated value (CV) until reduction amount reached (e.g., for |2|5|12| and Amt=-3, reduce CV to |4|12|, which is -2 from the first segment and -1 from the second segment)
- Amt reduction is limited to the sum of the previous CV's individual numbers (e.g., for |4|12|, the reduction cannot exceed 16)
- Amt=F#, indicates a multiplying factor, and the CV's numbers need to be updated
- The CV has no max (could have dozens to hundreds of individual numbers, with numbers going from 1 to 100,000+), other than any max applied by Excel itself on string length

Comment: Can you explain the logic. For example why do we go from `|2|5|12|` to `|4|12|`?

Comment: The numbers are essentially capturing individual transactions.  Positive numbers are concatenated to the end of the previous entry.  Negative numbers, however, reduce the existing entries.

Comment: How? Looking at the example it is far from clear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51861551/edit) your question with an explanation

Comment: The concatenated entries keep track of balances of the individual transactions.

For example, the |2|5|12| represents existing balances of 2, 5, and 12.  When the entry of -3 occurs on 3/25/18, it reduces the 2 to 0 (eliminates that balance), and reduces the 5 to 4.  The concatenated entry is adjusted to reflect the new balances.  In terms of respective balances, it would look like |0|4|12, but balances of |0| are removed.

Comment: If you are on Excel 2016 or Office365, you can use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) which will work with arrays instead of CONCATENATE

Comment: Updated the original question to address additional comments.  The max extent of the minus amount is the sum of the individual numbers of the previous concatenated value, and there is no max value.  Also, unfortunately, possibly the simplest solution (the TEXTJOIN function) isn't available in my case, since I'm limited to 2007.

Comment: The complexities of decrementing and applying factors to accounts requires an iterative approach, especially since the number of concatenated accounts is variable.  I can't imagine a solution where you can do it with a single formula per row.  However, it may be possible to add a bunch of formula columns between `Amt` and `Concatenated Data`.  You would have to create formula columns for the maximum number of accounts that may be concatenated.  Then you could conditionally combined them into your `|#|#|#|#|#|` string.  It would still be quite complicated, but may be doable without using VBA.

Comment: Correction : you'd mentioned ".. which is -12 from the first segment and -1 from the second segment)"  <--- should be ' -2 ' instead of ' -12 ' right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: it needs to be in one cell?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the numbers stored and shown separated with `|`? You could calculate the result of the amount as one number like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",$B2)),SUM($B$2:$B2)/RIGHT($B2,LEN($B2)-FIND("/",$B2)),IF(LEFT($B2,1)="F",SUM($B$2:$B2)*RIGHT(LEN($B2)-1),$B$2:$B2)))`. This is provided that your amt-data starts counting at `B2`

Comment: @Doragon, it would need to be in a single cell for a given row, but not necessarily one cell for the whole worksheet.

Comment: @E33 I’m not sure it’s possible, since you will have to use substring to get each number, and then concentrate  then all at the end to get it back on a string. There is a max on the number of nested functions (50) and even if this cell won’t pass that, the more functions in a cell, the more it lags, and one cell might update faster than the cell it’s referencing.

Comment: @P.b, each discrete value has to be tracked.  There are additional factors that have been omitted that can affect only some of the discrete values.  That portion I have worked out, though.  Basically, the thing here would be like keeping a running total of multiple subtotals.

Comment: @Doragon, yeah, I've only been able to do this via VBA.  The thing that makes this particularly difficult is that the string isn't a fixed length (or even a fixed number of delimiters), and it's not a simple addition/subtraction.

Comment: @E33 if you were able to use the rest of the row, instead of one cell per row, I think it would be possible. But when you limit yourself to one cell you loose a lot of functions that would help, and mainly you condense things more than they can functionally go

Comment: @Doragon, to clarify, there is space in the other columns, so that availability of extra columns isn't particularly the issue.  The issue there is not knowing how many columns would be needed.  For some instances, we'd be talking a few columns, and in others, thousands (which would then make the overall table extremely difficult to use).

Comment: @E33 would it work to instead of having everything in one cell, or making thousands of cells, to maybe make a formula for about 10 numbers in each cell, that way there aren’t so many cells, but not so cramped?

Answer (score 1):

**HIGH LEVEL**

1. Four parts to this solution
2. They satisfy pre-requisites (2007 compatibility, no VB, no Office 365 requirement, no custom VB functions, provide for complete 'dynamic' nature of variable length of cells to concatenate)
3. Caveat: to best knowledge / research, there is no parsimonious single-cell function & therefore an interim step has been proposed)
4. One more caveat: I imagine the simple 'hack' of wrapping a graph around the delimited data is out of question (see 'Other/Various' below ☺)

**PARTS 1-4**

Accompanying parts 1-4 below are functions which relate to the following screenshot:

[image: Excel Depiction of Dynamic Concatenation Solution - Excel 2007]

I have also uploaded / amended to meet requirements of Google Sheets (see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pMTlJgQcdu0p-mX1nfWU0C3aJMrapa7GNAhoU3UWTVI/edit?usp=sharing))
Parts 1 & 2:

Similar in that they rely upon FilterXML technique to count component / terms, and split cells respectively:

*Part 1:*

```
=COUNT(2*TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<AllText><Num>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(D12,2,LEN(D12)-1),LEN(MID(D12,2,LEN(D12)-1))-1),"|","</Num><Num>")&"</Num></AllText>","//Num")))
```

Note: google sheets doesn't recognise FilterXML, so have amended technique/functions accordingly.  For instance, above can be determined using counta on the split cells in Part 2 (easier / much more simpler than proposed approach above, albeit less robust given any cells lying to the right of the split cells will interfere with ordinary functionality of this approach).

*Part 2:*

It's either a manual approach, a fancy series of 'mid' &/or substitute / left/right functions, or the following FilterXML code which, per various sources (e.g. [here](https://officepowerups.com/2013/12/17/excel-webservice-function/#:%7E:text=The%20Excel%20WEBSERVICE%20function%2C%20ENCODEURL,Suite%20add%2Din%20for%20Excel.)) should be compatible with Excel 2007:

```
=IF(LEFT(C12,1)="F",1*SUBSTITUTE(C12,"F",""),1)*TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<AllText><Num>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(D12,2,LEN(D12)-1),LEN(MID(D12,2,LEN(D12)-1))-1),"|","</Num><Num>")&"</Num></AllText>","//Num"))
```

Commonality with Part 1 (re: FilterXML) can be seen - the only difference is that the count(Part 1) has been replaced with the transformation (multiplicative factor, as given in O.P's Q).

*Part 3*

Nothing fancy here - a simple concatenation (which is a far cry from a 'recursive' substitution function, I know, but hey - it does the trick and can always be placed in a mirror copy of the original sheet to avoid space issues/cell interaction issues)

```
=IF(H12="","",IF(G24="","|","")&G24&H12&"|")
```

*Part 4*

Thanks to the number of terms derived in Part 1, an offset function can easily determine the final cell pertaining to the concatenated 'build up' of 'transformed' values (per Part 3):

```
=OFFSET(H31,0,E31-1,1,1)
```

**OTHER / VARIOUS**

Various other proposals and 'workarounds' exist; unfortunately, these appear to fall short in one way or another of the pre-requisites set forth, videlicit:

a) Function/formula based
b) No VB
c) Excel 2007
d) Dynamic (variable/unknown number of terms)

1. Manual: e.g. function = concatenate(transpose(desired range)), and then components of the concatenate function and pressing F9 to convert to calculated values, which are readily applicable in the concatenate function.  Disadvantage: time consuming in relation to 'automated solution' (needs to be done for each applicable toy).  Advantage: no additional 'spreadsheet real estate' required, quicker/straightforward implementation in first instance.
2. Variants of the 'build-up' method: e.g. per Part 3, however, this alone does not ensure for an automated approach across an unknown number of terms in the original concatenated list.
3. Have mentioned in a previous solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709691/nth-occurrence-vlookup/66723085#66723085)), but may be case that you are eligible for Office 365 functionality whilst on a previous version of Excel (see Office Insider [here](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows))
4. Other proposals (above/below in this forum mind you) propose textjoin (so not sure if this is a comprehension issue or what ☺)
5. And yes, as alluded to at outset, you can easily achieve the desired outcome using a simple graph! Just for fun then, sort the data in reverse order, and include the split/delimited values as a bar graphs' "x-values" (which, by defn. for this type of graph, will now appear along the ordinary Cartesian 'y/vertical' axis)...

[image: Graphical solution]

Zero points for this but thought it was an interesting discovery on my part!
(and if still in doubt, here's what the 'graph' would look like if I didn't kill everything except for the axis labels...):

[image: Funny little graph - probably quickest solution!!]

Numerous references for relevant other items above, including research areas, as follows:

- [Excel Champs](https://officepowerups.com/2013/12/17/excel-webservice-function/#:%7E:text=The%20Excel%20WEBSERVICE%20function%2C%20ENCODEURL,Suite%20add%2Din%20for%20Excel.https://excelchamps.com/blog/concatenate-a-range-of-cells/)
- [StackOverflow - alternative applications for FilterXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925218/how-to-concatenate-xml-children-in-filterxml)

**JUST ONE MORE THING...**

In true Columbo style modus operandi, other ideas/approaches considered:

- Application of pivot table?
- Constructing matrices: I got a solution with a series of offset functions, but couldn't think of a feasible way to implement given space issues
- Converting the split cells into a long digit through summation: e.g. 8 22 16 = 80  000 + 22 00 + 16.  Using a substitute function with text (long digit, "General") I was able to successfully introduce the delimiter character ('|') for pairs of adjacent 'tuples' (e.g. I could get '8|2216', '822|16', but then a 'build up' formula where one cell depends upon converted values of the previous and so one was required once more, which landed me back to the proposal I have set out above
- fyi - the matrix consideration only solves tuples of 2, for n-dimensional /combination one would need to 'pass' a string of characters over its mirror copy - e.g. {6,10,22} would pass over {6,10,22}, ignoring duplicate values would yield a trapezium as follows:

| 6 | 10 | **22** |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 6 | **10** | 22 |  |  |
|  |  | **6** | 10 | 22 |  |

after the copy has 'passed' over the original (first row), we have the desired combination (22,10,6) (on the 'diagonal' such a matrix).  This is akin to how Fourier Transforms work (kind of); but that aside, it was tempting to construct a matrix like this, but couldn't be bothered at this stage.

Will probably turn out to be a far simpler way that someone comes up with (I won't be the only person surprised based upon the various sources I've considered...)