# How to concatenate XML children in FILTERXML

Tags: excel, xml

I may have an XML string like this

```
<data>
    <a> “one” </a>
    <a> “three” </a>
    <a> “two” </a>
</data>
```

which, in an Excel cell would look like this.

```
[A2] = "<data><a>one</a><a>three</a><a>two</a></data>"
```

I want to extract the numbers "two" and "three", in that sequence, using the FILTERXML() function. I know how to do that with this formula.

```
=FILTERXML(A2,"/data/a[3]") & FILTERXML(A2","/data/a[2]"))
```

However, there must be a way to join the two elements in a single function call, like

```
=FILTERXML(A2,"/data/a[3]" & "/data/a[2]")
```

In fact, I imagine that it should be even simpler than that. Can anyone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return those two as an array, I would use:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3,2})
```

or

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3;2})
```

If you want to return them as a concatenated string, you could use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3;2}))
```

Here are some usage examples per your comment/question

[image]

I did not provide examples of  `SUM` as that would return a zero, since your data is not numeric.

Note that if you have an older version of Excel, without dynamic arrays, you may (or may not) have to use `ctrl+shift+enter` to confirm the formulas, and/or for the simple `=INDEX(…` formula, enter it over several cells as an array.

```
C2:  =INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3,2})
C4:  =INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3;2})

C7:  =COUNTA(INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3,2}))
C8:  =MATCH("“three”",INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a"),{3,2}),0)
```

Comment: Thank you. Which alternative syntax to the first INDEX did you want to show in the second?

Comment: I can't use TEXTJOIN but I failed to use the range your formula creates in a function like SUM, MATCH or COUNTA. Please show me how I might do that.

Comment: @Variatus One version returns a vertical array; the other a horizontal array.

Comment: @Variatus See edit for some examples of use of the array in a formula.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! For the life of me, I can't see the difference between your first INDEX formula and the second. Can you add a red arrow for me, please? I got your example in C2:D2 to work entering it array formula in Excel 2013, but C4:C5 doesn't want to do as you command. C7 returns 1 and C8 #N/A - same result when entered as array or not. I also failed to extract any but the first value from the index, also trying both ways.

Comment: @Variatus The difference between the two `INDEX` functions is in the array constant (comma separated vs semi-colon separated).  I suspect your `#N/A` result is because you entered `three` surrounded by straight quotes and not the left and right quote marks as it is in your original data; or perhaps you did not use `ctrl+shift+enter` when confirming; or both?

Comment: Thanks for the red arrow. That worked. All the others, that is all attempts at using the INDEX function to parse the array, don't. I suppose it must be a matter of my version of Excel. I've learned most of what I wanted to know. Let's call it a day. Thank you again!

Comment: FYI Posted an alternative `FILTERXML` solution referencing positions directly as a late post.

Comment: @T.M.What is the advantage when the desired order is `position 3 | position 2`?

Answer (score 2):

Use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML(A2,"/data/a["&{3,2}&"]"))
```

Depending on one's version it may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thank you. I can't use TEXTJOIN but I tried `SUM(FILTERXML(A2,"/data/a["&{3,2}&"]"))` successfully after replacing my text with numbers. `SUM(FILTERXML(A2,"//a["&{3,2}&"]"))` seems to work equally well, presumably because there is only one parent in my string. But I don't seem to be able to get `MATCH("two",INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"/data/a["&{3,2}&"]")),1),0)` to work. Is that as it should be?

Comment: Did you use ctrl-shift-enter?

Comment: FYI Posted an alternative FILTERXML solution referencing positions directly as a late post.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative by addressing node positions directly**

If the output order doesn't matter you can apply the `AND` logic juxtaposing both subordinated conditions in brackets within the XPath string:

```
    =FILTERXML(A2,"//a[position()>=2][position()<=3]")
```

*(Side note: an additional `OR` condition would have been written into the bracket separated by `|`)*

---

If however you persist on getting the third item first you'll need the `INDEX()` function in addition:

```
    =INDEX(FILTERXML(A2,"//a[position()>=2][position()<=3]"),{2;1})
```

**Note:** *Pay attention to the semi-colon notation for vertical alignment (colon notation in most languages for a "flat" representation) as well as to the index arguments now interchanging two xml contents only, 
i.e. getting the second one first and the first one at last :-)*

Comment: Thank you for adding to my knowledge. You may like to correct the typo in the INDEX formula. As a side note for others who might be as unfamiliar with the subject as I, the character preceding the OR condition is a pipe (Chr(124))