# nth Occurrence Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know there are many questions regarding this topic, but I am legit stuck and keep confusing myself. Here is the issue. I have two tables:

**Table 1:** Patients and CPT values that all say SURG (Columns A and B respectively)

| PATNO | CPT |
| --- | --- |
| 58903 | SURG |
| 58903 | SURG |

**Table 2:** Has same patients but with actual codes I need to match with Table 1. (Columns E and F respectively)

| PATNO | CPT |
| --- | --- |
| 58903 | 29882 |
| 58903 | 6447 |

**The issue:** Vlookup only gets first lookup value and I need to populate all the occurrences, not just the first. For Patient 58903, I would like my vlookup to populate the first instance with 29882 and the second with 6447 if possible.

Would an index and match be the way to do this in one go? Or using a helper column somewhere? VBA? The dataset is large and can't do it manually.

Comment: If you have Office 365 subscription you can use FILTER.

Comment: Like do one vlookup, then filter out the first occurrence and do it again?

Comment: no there is a formula FILTER() that will return all that match a certain criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED 5 DIFFERENT WAYS*:

*Note: 4th and 5th methods are similar and based upon previous/earlier response as cited in summary table below.*

---

### **1) Summary: methods, pros & cons**

---

1. This response includes five different approaches (per screenshot below)
2. In descending order of personal preference:

| Method | Advantage | Disadvantage | Comment(s) | Function (refer to screenshot) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1) Index ¦ Filter | Simplest | Requires 365 account'; processing speed: very large lookup tables | May be eligible for access (see [here](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows)) | *=INDEX(FILTER($B$12:$B$17,$A$12:$A$17=A2),SUM(1*(A$2:A2=A2)))* |
| (2) Offset ¦ Small | Quick, no license restrictions | More complex re: audit / review due to offset function | n/a | *=OFFSET($P$2,SMALL(IF($O$2:$O$7=A2,ROW($P$2:$P$7)-ROW($P$2)+1,""),SUM(1*(A$2:A2=A2))),0,1,1)* |
| (3) Index ¦ Small | Quick; no license restrictions; easier to review | Increased complexity re: functions | *(1)-(3): text & numeric 'lookups' can be used* | *=INDEX($B$13:$B$18,SMALL(IF($A$13:$A$18=A2,ROW($B$13:$B$18)-ROW($B$13)+1,""),SUM(1*(A$2:A2=A2))))* |
| (4) Small (i.e. outer fn. only) | Quick; simplest re: functions | Only suitable for numeric 'lookups' | Slight improvement vs. method 5 | *=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$12:$A$17=A2,$B$12:$B$17,""),SUM(1*(A$2:A2=A2))),"n/a")* |
| (5) Small ¦ Index* | No additional benefits to method 4 | Slightly more complex than method 4 | Correction for earlier response (citing: re: other response: [[P-b][2]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b) | *=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$12:$A$17=A2,$B$12:$B$17,""),SUM(1*(A$2:A2=A2))),"n/a")* |

---

### **2) Excel screenshot**

---

[image]

Comment: Unable to add comments elsewhere- citing P.b (only other response to date).  Great attempt, gave me a few ideas (e.g. 4, 5, per above) - but your method otherwise fails beyond 'a' - e.g. try 'b'.  This happens because your rows($1:1) needs to 'reset' after doing the "a's" - not start from from 4+ (would be 4 if you put "b" in cell H5 in your screenshot).  To get around this, I deploy / prefer using "sum(1*(H$2:H2 = H2))" instead of your proposed "Rows($1:1)".... Let me know if any questions/challenges in this regard... Ta

Answer (score 0):

If you have office365 the suggestion of Scott Craner suits best.
If you run a ln older version of Excel a formula like this would get the desired result:[image]
This is based on the value you want your match on is positioned in one cell.